# Javascript count unique array occurrence

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following were an output from an array returned by following function:

```
$scope.variantOptions = $scope.variantLists.join(", ");
```

`medium,small,medium,small,small`

How can I sort the result, so it represent the output as:

`medium x 2,small x 3`

EDIT

`addCount` function:

```
$scope.addCount = function($index){

        $scope.counter = 1;

        if($scope.activity['variant'][$index]['count'] != undefined ){

            $scope.counter = parseInt($scope.activity['variant'][$index]["count"]) +1;

            $scope.variantLists.push($scope.activity['variant'][$index]['variant_dtl_name']);

        }


        $scope.activity['variant'][$index]["count"] =  $scope.counter;

        console.log(arraySimplify($scope.variantLists));


    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ask same question. This is same as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728073/angularjs-unique-count-element-in-an-array). Just edit the previous question to add more info.

Comment: Also, show your efforts when asking question.

Comment: What you have tried so far to attain the result?

Comment: @Tushar, the previous questions seems to be complicated to be understood and difficult to recreate a jsfiddle sample. So i make it easier example here.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava so far I tried `var obj = { };
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
   obj[arr[i]] = (obj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
}` to make a count, but it return me just an empty `obj`

Comment: nope if I jsfiddle it I can see the output http://jsfiddle.net/2dw9104p/

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava adding inside the loop, I am getting count as `Object {adult: 1}
activityCtrl.js:186 Object {adult: 3}
activityCtrl.js:186 Object {adult: 6}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass your '$scope.variantLists' arry into this function it will give you the expected result.

```
     function arraySimplify(arr){
        arr.sort();
        var rslt = [], element =arr[0] ,count = 0 ;

        if(arr.length === 0) return; //exit for empty array

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            //count the occurences
            if(element !== arr[i]){
                rslt.push(element + ' x ' + count);
                count =1;
                element = arr[i];
            }
            else{
                count++;
            }
        }
        rslt.push(element + ' x ' + count);
        return rslt.join(', ');
    }
```

Comment: what is format of the result is you are expecting, an object or a string?

Comment: you can define this as function as scope variable pass your `$scope.variantLists` array into that get the result. `$scope.variantOptions = $scope.arraySimplify($scope.variantLists)`

Comment: I already edit my question. The code is for `addCount` how does your function work in case of `minusCount` ?

Comment: what you mean minus count? there no way to `count` get minus values?

Comment: No, I mean removing the item back from the list. Can your method update the count? How can I modify the above function handling removing the item from the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95206/discussion-between-azzi-and-ngman).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working:

```
for (var i = 0;i < $scope.variantLists.length;i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = (obj[arr[i]] || 0) + 1; 
}
```

Gives you an object:

```
obj = {medium: 2, small: 3}
```

To see it without having to go into the console, you can just alert the object after the 'for' loop:

```
alert(obj);
```

To get the EXACT string you want:

```
var string = "";
for (var key in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var count = validation_messages[key];
       string += key + " x " + count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re: "*To see it without having to go into the console, you can just alert the object*" in some browsers that will just display `[object Object]`.

Comment: Ok, then just go into the console.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may look like an entry in Code Golf but this is one of the rare times when `Array.reduce` makes sense.

```
var r = a.sort().reduce(
                   function(A,i){
                     A.set(i, (!A.get(i))?1:A.get(i)+1);
                     return A;
                   },new Map());
```

Which makes basically what Jon Stevens proposed but in a more modern and highly illegible way. I used a `Map` because the order in a normal `Object` dictionary is not guaranteed in a `forEach` loop. Here `r.forEach(function(v,k,m){console.log(k + ":" + v);})` gets printed in the order of insertion.

Comment: The OP hasn't asked for any order. This rather needlessly imposes a requirement for an ECMAScript 2015 feature that is not well supported yet (though likely this is Node.js, but the OP hasn't tagged it as such).

Comment: The prespecified result was given by the OP in alphabetical order; by chance or not, I don't know. `Map` has support in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. I'm not sure about Edge (can't test on this machine) but believe it supports it, too. Safari doesn't for now. Also: it's in ECMA-262 which is the current standard, nearly half a year old, produced by a committee with *all* the big players in it. BTW: no restrictions by the OP regarding legacy browsers, the post is tagged `javascript`.

Comment: EMCA-262 is the name of the standard, the current version is the 6th edition, also known as ECMAScript 2015. There are many who do not use the most recent edition of a browser from "big players", or one of their browsers at all (see [*Netmarketshare*](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)). There is a compatibility table at [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), there are others ([*Kangax*](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), [*PointedEars*](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/)).